# How to disable a field or make it readonly in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, field, form-api

I am trying to disable couple of fields and make them readonly via hook_page_alter(). I was able to do check if user is viewing the page edit section (the form edit)

```
$page['content']['system_main']['#node_edit_form'] == TRUE)
```

then when I tried to disable couple of fields, I found that select list can be disabled by this code:

```
$page['content']['system_main']['field_my_field_name_a_select_list']['und']['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
```

but if I use the following code it doesn't work:

```
$page['content']['system_main']['field_my_field_name_a_select_list']['und']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
```

I also found that I can not use the same code to disable a text area field:

```
$page['content']['system_main']['field_my_text_area']['und']['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
```

The above code doesn't disable the text area, but the same code can disable the select list!

Then I tried hook_form_alter() to do the same thing, and I was able to disable fields and when I checked the rendered array from $page array, I saw that it shows:

```
$page['content']['system_main']['field_my_field_name_a_select_list']['und']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
```

but when I set the same code in hook_page_alter(), it didn't work. Looks like something else will override it, I thought that hook_page_alter() is the last place to change markup.

Any idea what is the best way to  disable/readonly any kind of field, inside hook_page_alter() in drupal 7?

Thank you

Answer (score 21):

It works for text fields^

```
$form['field_secured_title']['und']['0']['value']['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't have issue with $form, what I am asking is how to do it by $page array, they way Drupal 7 like it. I mean using the new hook_page_alter() function.

Comment: if you want to change fields from a form, the way Drupal like it is to do it with `hook_form_alter`

Comment: API doc is wrong and misguiding http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/6#disabled

Comment: Sivaji - you are linking the D6 API doc, not D7.

Comment: There is a #disabled parameter in Form API https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#disabled

Answer (score 2):

Like it said in [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes)

You can use attributes :

```
$form['#attributes'] = array('disabled' => TRUE);
```