# drupal 7 make field required in form_user_profile_form_alter

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I use Drupal 7.x. 
I add several fields in the user profile form.

In the registration i don't need them, but in the first login it must be filled.
I can't use Profile2 module.

In my module:

```
function mymodule_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {      
          $form['field_test_field']['#required'] = 'TRUE';   
}
```

The function is fired, but don't make it required.

I tried also:

```
$form['field_test_field'][0]['#required'] = 'TRUE';  
$form['#field_info']['field_test_field']['required'] = '1';
```

How can make an `user_profile_form`  field Required in the form alter?

Answer (score 2):

The following example can be used for text field:

`$form['field_full_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['value']['#required'] = TRUE;`

Second example is for email field:

`$form['field_custom_email_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['email']['#required'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 0):

You're currently setting #required to a string (using single quotes) instead the boolean it needs to be. Give this a go `$form['field_test_field']['#required'] = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: [How to disable a field or make it readonly in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399380/how-to-disable-a-field-or-make-it-readonly-in-drupal-7)

```
$form['field_secured_title']['und']['0']['value']['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
```

This worked.

But if i use multi language will it still work?

sorry for my English.

Comment: The `und` key defines the language (currently undefined). In fact, it's probably better if you use the constant `LANGUAGE_NONE` instead of `und`.  This is what you would need to change if you are using a different language.